Create an Outlook Add-in using an xml manifest file that adds a drop down menu on the main ribbon
So I have an Outlook Add-in that displays a little drop down menu - it only appears on certain tabs and I have to click Apps on a Add-in group, then my add-in to get things happening (too many clicks in my view). What I want to for it to just be added to the end of the Home tab, shown below:
Ribbon screen shot
This is my manifest file:
<Hosts>
  <Host xsi:type="MailHost">

    <DesktopFormFactor>
      <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />

      <!-- Message compose form -->
      <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
        <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
          <Group id="msgComposeDemoGroup">
            <Label resid="groupLabel" />
            <!-- Menu (dropdown) button -->
            <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="msgComposeMenuButton">
              <Label resid="menuComposeButtonLabel" />
              <Supertip>
                <Title resid="menuComposeSuperTipTitle" />
                <Description resid="menuComposeSuperTipDescription" />
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="red-icon-16" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="red-icon-32" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="red-icon-80" />
              </Icon>
              <Items>
                <Item id="msgComposeMenuItem1">
                  <Label resid="menuItem1ComposeLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="menuItem1ComposeLabel" />
                    <Description resid="menuItem1ComposeTip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="red-icon-16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="red-icon-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="red-icon-80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>addMsg1ToBody</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Item>
                <Item id="msgComposeMenuItem2">
                  <Label resid="menuItem2ComposeLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="menuItem2ComposeLabel" />
                    <Description resid="menuItem2ComposeTip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="red-icon-16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="red-icon-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="red-icon-80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>addMsg2ToBody</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Item>
                <Item id="msgComposeMenuItem3">
                  <Label resid="menuItem3ComposeLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="menuItem3ComposeLabel" />
                    <Description resid="menuItem3ComposeTip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="red-icon-16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="red-icon-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="red-icon-80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>addMsg3ToBody</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Item>
              </Items>
            </Control>
            <!-- Task pane button -->
            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeOpenPaneButton">
              <Label resid="paneComposeButtonLabel" />
              <Supertip>
                <Title resid="paneComposeSuperTipTitle" />
                <Description resid="paneComposeSuperTipDescription" />
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="green-icon-16" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="green-icon-32" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="green-icon-80" />
              </Icon>
              <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                <SourceLocation resid="composeTaskPaneUrl" />
              </Action>
            </Control>
          </Group>
        </OfficeTab>
      </ExtensionPoint>

      <!-- Appointment compose form -->
      <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
        <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
          <Group id="apptComposeDemoGroup">
            <Label resid="groupLabel" />
            <!-- Function (UI-less) button -->
            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="apptComposeFunctionButton">
              <Label resid="funcComposeButtonLabel" />
              <Supertip>
                <Title resid="funcComposeSuperTipTitle" />
                <Description resid="funcComposeSuperTipDescription" />
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="blue-icon-16" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="blue-icon-32" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="blue-icon-80" />
              </Icon>
              <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                <FunctionName>addDefaultMsgToBody</FunctionName>
              </Action>
            </Control>
            <!-- Menu (dropdown) button -->
            <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="apptComposeMenuButton">
              <Label resid="menuComposeButtonLabel" />
              <Supertip>
                <Title resid="menuComposeSuperTipTitle" />
                <Description resid="menuComposeSuperTipDescription" />
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="red-icon-16" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="red-icon-32" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="red-icon-80" />
              </Icon>
              <Items>
                <Item id="apptComposeMenuItem1">
                  <Label resid="menuItem1ComposeLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="menuItem1ComposeLabel" />
                    <Description resid="menuItem1ComposeTip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="red-icon-16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="red-icon-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="red-icon-80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>addMsg1ToBody</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Item>
                <Item id="apptComposeMenuItem2">
                  <Label resid="menuItem2ComposeLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="menuItem2ComposeLabel" />
                    <Description resid="menuItem2ComposeTip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="red-icon-16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="red-icon-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="red-icon-80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>addMsg2ToBody</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Item>
                <Item id="apptComposeMenuItem3">
                  <Label resid="menuItem3ComposeLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="menuItem3ComposeLabel" />
                    <Description resid="menuItem3ComposeTip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="red-icon-16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="red-icon-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="red-icon-80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>addMsg3ToBody</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Item>
              </Items>
            </Control>
            <!-- Task pane button -->
            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="apptComposeOpenPaneButton">
              <Label resid="paneComposeButtonLabel" />
              <Supertip>
                <Title resid="paneComposeSuperTipTitle" />
                <Description resid="paneComposeSuperTipDescription" />
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="green-icon-16" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="green-icon-32" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="green-icon-80" />
              </Icon>
              <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                <SourceLocation resid="composeTaskPaneUrl" />
              </Action>
            </Control>
          </Group>
        </OfficeTab>
      </ExtensionPoint>

      <!-- Message read form -->
      <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
        <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
          <Group id="msgReadDemoGroup">
            <Label resid="groupLabel" />
            <!-- Menu (dropdown) button -->
            <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="msgReadMenuButton">
              <Label resid="menuReadButtonLabel" />
              <Supertip>
                <Title resid="menuReadSuperTipTitle" />
                <Description resid="menuReadSuperTipDescription" />
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="red-icon-16" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="red-icon-32" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="red-icon-80" />
              </Icon>
              <Items>
                <Item id="msgReadMenuItem1">
                  <Label resid="menuItem1ReadLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="menuItem1ReadLabel" />
                    <Description resid="menuItem1ReadTip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="red-icon-16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="red-icon-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="red-icon-80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>getItemClass</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Item>
                <Item id="msgReadMenuItem2">
                  <Label resid="menuItem2ReadLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="menuItem2ReadLabel" />
                    <Description resid="menuItem2ReadTip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="red-icon-16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="red-icon-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="red-icon-80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>getDateTimeCreated</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Item>
                <Item id="msgReadMenuItem3">
                  <Label resid="menuItem3ReadLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="menuItem3ReadLabel" />
                    <Description resid="menuItem3ReadTip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="red-icon-16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="red-icon-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="red-icon-80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>getItemID</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Item>
              </Items>
            </Control>
            <!-- Task pane button -->
            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
              <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
              <Supertip>
                <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="green-icon-16" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="green-icon-32" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="green-icon-80" />
              </Icon>
              <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                <SourceLocation resid="readTaskPaneUrl" />
              </Action>
            </Control>
          </Group>
        </OfficeTab>
      </ExtensionPoint>

      <!-- Appointment read form -->
      <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentAttendeeCommandSurface">
        <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
          <Group id="apptReadDemoGroup">
            <Label resid="groupLabel" />
            <!-- Menu (dropdown) button -->
            <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="apptReadMenuButton">
              <Label resid="menuReadButtonLabel" />
              <Supertip>
                <Title resid="menuReadSuperTipTitle" />
                <Description resid="menuReadSuperTipDescription" />
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="red-icon-16" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="red-icon-32" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="red-icon-80" />
              </Icon>
              <Items>
                <Item id="apptReadMenuItem1">
                  <Label resid="menuItem1ReadLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="menuItem1ReadLabel" />
                    <Description resid="menuItem1ReadTip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="red-icon-16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="red-icon-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="red-icon-80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>getItemClass</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Item>
                <Item id="apptReadMenuItem2">
                  <Label resid="menuItem2ReadLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="menuItem2ReadLabel" />
                    <Description resid="menuItem2ReadTip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="red-icon-16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="red-icon-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="red-icon-80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>getDateTimeCreated</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Item>
                <Item id="apptReadMenuItem3">
                  <Label resid="menuItem3ReadLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="menuItem3ReadLabel" />
                    <Description resid="menuItem3ReadTip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="red-icon-16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="red-icon-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="red-icon-80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>getItemID</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Item>
              </Items>
            </Control>
            <!-- Task pane button -->
            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="apptReadOpenPaneButton">
              <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
              <Supertip>
                <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="green-icon-16" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="green-icon-32" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="green-icon-80" />
              </Icon>
              <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                <SourceLocation resid="readTaskPaneUrl" />
              </Action>
            </Control>
          </Group>
        </OfficeTab>
      </ExtensionPoint>

    </DesktopFormFactor>
  </Host>
</Hosts>

Help please??

You cover up 4 most important extension points and this is what you can do in terms of your add-on UI availability. You can use a couple of more from the list with very little benefit. The icon of the add-on appears in the arias you cannot control, unfortunately. This is up to every Outlook client (web, mac, desktop) how and where in the ribbons to display your add-on.

@SlavaIvanov - Thanks, you are saying that potentially Outlook desktop for Windows with classic ribbon might even shows these differently to the Outlook web version / and the 'New' Outlook desktop version?

Ah, I see:
"MessageReadCommandSurface
This extension point puts buttons in the command surface for the mail read view. In Outlook desktop, this appears in the ribbon."  :)

Yes, add-on placement and appearance, large/small icons, etc. will be/maybe different from client to client. As far as I understand, "new" Outlook desktop is not equal to Outlook for Web, but it looks alike.  And you are right "MessageReadCommandSurface" is the extension point which puts add-on icon on the "home" ribbon, while reading the message in the main view.

Thanks - OK, so the next question is 'How do I load this manifest into Outlook desktop/for Windows? (not the 'New' web looking Outlook) ?? So far I've been sideloading is via 'https://aka.ms/olksideload' and see it running in the browser. Documentation says do same thing and it should appear in the desktop version... I'm seeing nothing in Outlook desktop...

When sideload add-on from ANY Outlook client, you loading it into Exchange account of the user and it will be available on every client used by this user right away. This happens if the client supports declared minVersion of supported set.

Thanks, will look further into that @SlavaIvanov

OK, @SlavaIvanov - I seem to be unable to get this add-in to surface/show in Outlook windows/desktop. If I navigate to Manage Add-ins from desktop ver, it takes me to web page where I see the add-in loaded already and surfacing in Outlook in browser.
Are you saying my manifest needs tweaks in order for it to show in desktop outlook, a per this stuff:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements#specify-which-office-versions-and-platforms-can-host-your-add-in
??
